# SignalR await in hub method for long time

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr, signalr-hub

Hi,

I have a Hub on my server (azure webroles) with the following method:

```cs
public async Task<bool> Listen()
{
    var userid = ...;
    var observer = new BlackBoxObserver(userid){
        OnObserver = async (x) => { await Clients.Caller.NewMessage(x);}
    };
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    await observer.Stop();
    return true;
}
```

`BlackBoxObserver` is something unrelated to SignalR and calls `OnObserver` on specific events. In this sample the observer is stopped after 5 minutes and the hub method returns.

My question is if this is a valid approach regarding the use of Hubs? Is there a timeout that you have to respect regarding hub calls?

In this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219478/signalr-continuous-messaging) op states "*A hub doesn't feel like the right place to do this. A hub should be treated like an MVC/Web Api controller? So a request comes in, hub handles it, request is finished. End of story.*". And that a background worker may be a better idea.

So I guess I could let the client join a Sessiongroup when he calls the hubmethod and then call the observer from a backgroundthread and call the group as described as [here (asp.net/...)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub).
Would that be a better approach?

However, the easier and in some context also cleaner way for me would be the awaiting for a longer time in the hub method but I'm not sure if that may brings some problems with it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think those timeouts are configurable, but your question seems to be more conceptual.
The shown logic reminds me of a longpolling construction, the client sends a request to the server. Then the server waits until new information is available and then returns with the response to the client. This is exactly the sort of thing SignalR is trying to abstract away from you.

A better way would be to pass along the connectionId of the client who wants the information and use:

```
 var hub =GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("yourhubname");
 var client = hub.Clients.Client(connectionid);
```

to get a hub context and call the client back when you need/want to

Comment: Thanks for the input! My problem is that I don't really know where I could stall the connection while awaiting the observer. I don't can (and want) to have SignalR involved on my worker roles. The observer is the connecting part between worker roles and web roles. I could use a backgroundtask but it would feel cleaner and would have less code with the 'long polling like'-construct.The nasty long polling things like connection loss, reconnecting etc. would still be abstracted away by SignalR.  Or am I missing some other place for that kind of signalr work here?

Comment: I can understand your reluctance to create a dependancy upon signalr in your backend logic, but I think you can easily mitigate that by using Inversion Of Control and a dependancy injector or servicelocator pattern. Signalr in combination with a backplane such as azure servicebus is actually a great way to allow backend to update clients with relevent information

Comment: I understand your suggestion and I think that would be a good way. However I don't really need anything else from SignalR than websockets and proper connectionmanagement. And if not necessary I would prefere to not touch 'BlackBoxObserver' and the backendimplementation. So all I would need would be a good place for the awaiting of the observer.
However, if I would use signalr on the workerrole, the connection between workerroles and webroles would be done by signalrservicebus? Or would you let the clients directly connect to a selfhosting Signalr on the workerroles?

Comment: SignalR calls it a backplane and there are several implementations for it, one of them is the azure servicebus, another is SqlServer, and there are more. If you want to know more about it here is a good article http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr
I wouldn't let clients connect directly to your workerrole, simply initialize signalr with the same backplane as the webrole. Get the hub context and call the client with the connectionId. SignalR and the backplane will figure out where your message will needs to go.

Comment: okay thanks, so I'll may give the backplane solution a try. but I'll leave the question unanswerd because I still don't know if it would be a solution without any possible problems and it would still be the best/easiest solution for my project